# Pseudocode for finding if two letters are the same in a given input

Tags: arrays, duplicates, pseudocode

I have tried this code to return true if two letters are the same in a given input. {Input is given as an array}

```
Var_a = 0;
Var_b = 0;
Var_c = false;

While Var_a < input.length
{
    While Var_b < input.length
    {
        If input[Var_a] == = input[Var_b] && Var_a != Var_b{
            Var_c = true;
        }
        Var_b++;
    }
    Var_a++;
    Var_b = 0;
}

return Var_c;
```

Although this works on some examples, it does not seem to work on other examples.
Why is this? Is the code faulty or is it another issue that might have happened somewhere else?

Examples of where this works are the arrays [c, a, t] [k, a, y, a, k] and [b, o, b]
When the input is an unkown value however it does not work.

Comment: Would you please include an example where the code works and one where it does not work? Also, improving the indentation would make the code more readable

Comment: @user2314737 taken into consideration, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code snippet was correct after all and the error occured elsewhere within the program.